# Android drawing to the canvas a large bitmap, while keeping ratio and fill screen centered

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

i am loading a bitmap to be drawn but it is about 25px off from the right of the screen. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
   scaleWallpaperBitmap(R.drawable.board2);
   canvas.drawBitmap(board, 0, topOffset, null);

   private void scaleWallpaperBitmap(int res) {
      // read bitmap in project
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
      BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), res, options);
      int imgH = options.outHeight;
      int imgW = options.outWidth;

    // get new bitmap and find how to center it
    if (imgH == imgW) {
        // easy case of a square wallpaper
        if (screenH > screenW) {
            board = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), res,
                    screenW, screenW);
            verticalBitmapOffset = true;
            horizontalBitmapOffset = false;
            topOffset = (screenH - board.getHeight()) / 2;
        } else {
            board = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), res,
                    screenH, screenH);
            horizontalBitmapOffset = true;
            verticalBitmapOffset = false;
            leftOffset = (screenW - board.getWidth()) / 2;
        }
    } else {
        // ratio is now involved
    }
}
```

the rest of the methods are from the android docs here...

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

the image is almost perfectly scales and centered with it centered vertically, but it's not the full 
screen width it should be. There is about 25 px of free space on the right margin.

any feedback would be great!

thanks

Comment: Hi I am sort new to android and bitmaps, did you find why the right side is off yet, I am looking over this and thinking of some things it might be.